# Are there any US banks that allow you to make an international wire transfer online?

Tags: united-states, international, wire-transfer

I am an expat and right now I have to get someone to physically go to the bank to make the transfer for me each time.  It seems a bit ridiculous in this day and age of high tech and is a royal pain.  I would like to be able to simply go online and transfer the money where I need to send it.

Comment: This was already said somewhere on this site, but the questions asked here about US banking really amaze me. I am genuinely surprised there are banks which do *not* allow that.

Comment: I checked the past questions but didn't quite find what I was looking for.  If it has already been answered and someone can post the link that would be great.  I saw one post about wire transfers with no fees.  I don't care about the fees, as long as I can actually do an international wire transfer online.

Comment: I was referring to my comment, not your question. :)

Comment: Yes, there are US banks that will let you initiate an international wire transfer online.  Bank of America is one.  However, if your goal is to transfer money cheaply rather than quickly, then you should look into forex transfer services like US Forex.  There are several other questions on the site on this topic.

Comment: I second US Forex! But there are others that are cheaper and easier to deal with than most banks.

Answer (score 0):

If HSBC is an option for the country in which you're living I found they have very comprehensive banking services which are very helpful as an expat, including easy wire transfers initiated online. One key aspect is they will honor your US credit score which is helpful while you build a credit history in the new country. If you have enough on deposit with them you may qualify for the [HSBC Premier](https://www.hsbcpremier.com/1/2/) program which then gives you all of those free of charge.

That being said, I think their customer service and bureaucracy is horrendous. So once I had established myself locally I switched to a better local bank and use wire transfer services.

If you happen to be an expat in Canada there are now starting to be other options with TD and RBC.